# Screenshots have turned empty

Tags: macos

Screenshots taken since 2018-05-19 just produce an empty file rather than the png file that I expected when using Command-Shift-4.  Before that date they were working fine.

This is not a matter of screenshots going to the wrong place.  They are going to the right place which is iCloud Drive -> Documents -> Screenshots.  They are just empty files.

I have tried Force Quit on Finder but same result.  I have reset my mac several times but no change.

I am using macOS 10.13.4 on iMac.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean “I have reset my Mac several times”?

Comment: have you tried using Grab from your Utilities folder to take a screenshot?

Comment: NoahL: I should have said "restarted."

Comment: jmh: I had not heard of Grab but I'm trying it now.

Comment: jmk:  I have switched to Grab!  It works fine.